# Stored procedure returned value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've [implemented Bcrypt](http://blog.tcs.de/using-the-bcrypt-hash-algorithm-in-ms-sql-server/) on SQL Server. It's working fine.

I'm trying now to create a procedure where the user send his username and password (unhashed) and the procedure will return whether he is allowed to do so or not.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CONNECTION
    @Login_name VARCHAR(15),
    @not_hashed_pass CHAR(15)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @is_match BIT

    SET @is_match = (SELECT
                         dbo.CheckPassword(@not_hashed_pass, 
                                           (SELECT user_password FROM USERS 
                                            WHERE LOGIN_NAME= @Login_name)))

    IF @is_match = 1 
        PRINT 'connected'
    ELSE
        PRINT 'not connected'    
END
```

If I execute the procedure, I get the following result

> Not connected (@is_match = 0)

If I try to execute the query that I'm setting to `@is_match` however:

```
SELECT
    dbo.CheckPassword('azeqsd456789', 
                      (SELECT user_password FROM USERS 
                       WHERE LOGIN_NAME = 'Bob))
```

I get a `1` returned.

Both the query and procedure are executed with the same values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from using hashed passwords, your issue is a confusion of `char()` and `varchar()`.  Your procedure is declared as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CONNECTION (
    @Login_name varchar(15),
    @not_hashed_pass char(15)
)
```

The password you are passing in has 12 characters, so it is being padded with three spaces to `''azeqsd456789   '`.  Hence, they don't match.

I would suggest fixing the procedure definition:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CONNECTION (
    @Login_name varchar(15),
    @not_hashed_pass varchar(15)
)
```

But more importantly, I would strongly, strongly urge you to never use cleartext passwords and always hash them.

Comment: Your solution worked, thank you. I'm not storing any clear text passwords, I'm only sending them to that procedure to do the checking, the function work like this: CheckPassword('unhashed_password','hashed_password') and will compare them.